# Using Linux kernel config file from version to version

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, configuration, version

I have currently Linux Kernel 2.6, which works for my hardware. Now I want to compile Linux kernel 3.2 for the same hardware. Can I use the same `.config` of 2.6 directly for v3.2?

Is there any documentation/guide about how to do migrate the `.config` file from one kernel version to the other?

Answer (score 11):

You could use `make oldconfig`.

After you copy the 2.6 `.config` file, this make option will prompt to you for options in the current kernel source that are not found in the file. However, you will have to deal with choosing options out of the context, being difficult to give the right answer

**Further reading**:

- [What does “make oldconfig” do exactly - Linux kernel makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178526/what-does-make-oldconfig-do-exactly-linux-kernel-makefile)
- [Kernel/Upgrade - Gentoo Wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/Upgrade)

Answer (score 3):

Officially that is not recommended but you can do it and that's what I do.  You have to go through the build menus *very carefully*.  Things change (especially from 2.6 to 3.2), and without review you might end up with a lot of features and drivers you don't need.

I don't know of a migration guide but for kernel tweaking you may want to look at [Linux Kernel in a Nutshell](http://www.kroah.com/lkn/) from Greg Kroah-Hartmann; Chapters 7 and 8 will be of particular interest.  Written in 2006 it's a bit dated now but the contents are in essence still valid.